# Migrating SQL Server from EC2 to RDS vs Resize EC2 instance to improve application performance

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

We have an asp.net mvc web application with IIS and SQL Server residing in the same Amazon EC2 instance. We plan to move the database from the EC2 instance to Amazon RDS (to improve performance, the application is a bit slow at the moment - high cpu usage on the server).

I can't figure how this could be potentially helpful. On the flip side.

1. Migrating the database to Amazon RDS is not straightforward
2. Amazon RDS does not allow change in allocated storage for SQL Server
3. You can not use Backup / Restore to move DBs in and out of RDS

What are the benefits of migrating a SQL Server DB from EC2 to RDS? Rather than migrating to RDS should we look to resize the EC2 instance itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The biggest benefit to migrating to RDS, imo, is that your database becomes a database-as-a-service: you no longer need to manage it like you do when its running on your own instance. Automated backups, ability to take a snaphot and spin up an identical instance etc - all great things.

A while back I migrated all the SQL databases I supported to RDS and slept very well at night no longer needing to worry about them - but then, little by little, all the problems you mentioned became clearer and harder to ignore - inability to take backups of a single db and use locally, no longer have true administrator privileges to the DB or server and so ultimately, in a furry of activity migrated everything back to my own EC2 instances over a weekend.

IMO, until RDS allows you to take a local single-database backup and restore it to RDS, (and the opposite allow you to take a single database in RDS and make a backup that can be restored locally), I don't consider RDS to be a viable solution for me for any solution that is likely to need changes.

If I had a system that was 100% 'done', (if there is such a thing), and no need to enhance, modify, customize the database, than RDS has some benefits - but not having the ability to import/export backups is a show stopper for me as long as there is any chance I may need to make changes down the road - for the life of me can't figure out why AWS has not allowed/enabled this feature.

As to what you should do, first and foremost, you need to make sure that the database is really the bottleneck - it might not be.

If it is, then:

- If you are not already, start using a cache in front of your database
- Upgrade the size of your ec2 instance.
- Split the database onto its on EC2 instance.

Moving your database to RDS has some benefits, but an immediate boost in performance is not necessarily one of them.

Comment: As of November 2022, RDS for SQL Server now allows taking transaction log backups of a single database and doing whatever you want with them.